# Excel 2011 & 365 – 2nd user cannot open password protected file which is already opened by 1st user

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, afp

Infos: Mac environment, AFP Share on Synology, Sierra 10.12.6

With Office 2011, when a password protected file is opened and another user tries to open it, it asks whether you want to open the file in read-only mode and tells you which user is using the file. This is expected and needed in our environment.

Now, with Office 365 on one of our PCs, this is not possible anymore. When the second user (Office 365) tries to open the already opened file (Office 2011) it gives the following error:
[image: Error Message]
If I want to "repair" the seemingly corrupted file, a second error pops up:
[image: 2nd Error Message]

The same can be observed when the file is first opened on a Mac with Office 2016 and then on the Mac with Office 365 (or vice versa). Excel versions are: Office 365 Ver: 16.17, Office 2016 Ver: 16.16.2

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this happen on all the Macs in your environment?

Comment: At this time we have the new Office installations only on 2 macs for evaluation purposes.

Comment: It might be worth performing a disk/permissions check on the mac hard disk to see if everything is alright with program files... disk `First Aid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: The root of the cause is the Synology AFP Service.

I contacted Synology Support and they could reproduce the errors.

The developers know about this issue and are working on it.

Hope this helps anyone who has the same problem.